# how can i download file using click method using perl?

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

I am trying to download xls file from website
http://www.ncdex.com/MarketDataAction_bhavCopy.action

using Mechanize module click method,
but it gives error like :

Error POSTing http://www.ncdex.com/MarketDataAction_bhavCopySubmit.action: Not Found at click_method.pl line 6.

Here is my code:

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
my $url = 'http://www.ncdex.com/MarketDataAction_bhavCopy.action';
$mech->get( $url );
$mech->submit_form(
                fields      => {
                        'dateSelected' => '13/03/2017',
                }
        );
$mech->click_button(
                name => "buttonType",
                id => "buttonType",
                value => "xls Format",
                type => "submit"
        );

print $mech->content();
```

I want to download xls file from this website for date 13/03/2017 or any other date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly hit the url as below and write data to a .xls file

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(autocheck => 0);
$mech->get("http://www.ncdex.com/MarketDataAction_bhavCopySubmit.action?bhavTitle=bhav&dateSelected=13%2F03%2F2017&buttonType=xls+Format");
my $data = $mech->content;
print $data;
```

You can check the code by running it and redirecting output to .xls file
Eg:- perl test.pl > output.xls

Comment: how do you get this url?

Comment: You can get this using a debugging tool. For eg:- Live http header in firefox